# Fundamental theorem of arithmetic question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $b \in \mathbb{Z} $.  Prove that if $p$ is a prime number such that $p | b^2$, then $p|b$.

A certain theorem can be used to get this proof set up.  I know the general rule that this scenario is true and the concept behind it, but I am unable to find the right starting point to solve this proof.  I know that if p divides bc then it dives b or c.

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Comment: every integer n except 0 and 1 is a product of primes?

Comment: @D-Man That's the easy *existence* half of the theorem. You also need the other half, viz. the *uniqueness* of prime factorizations. What is the "certain theorem""?

Comment: @BillDubuque that is new to me. I have only been taught that half to my knowledge.

Comment: Do you know Euclid's Lemma, $\,\gcd(a,b)=1,\ a\mid bc\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid c,\,$ or do you know Bezout's Identity for the gcd?

Comment: yes I know Euclid's Lemma, just didnt have it written down as that.

Comment: Which version of Euclid's Lemma do you know?

Comment: the only thing that was taught was the proof of if p divides bc then p divides c or d.  and that thm. was proved using the fact that (p,b) = 1 and p divides bc so p divides c, then was used to show p was not 1 and not ppositive or negative p to prove the theorem.  Im not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: @D-Man That version of Euclid's Lemma implies that if a prime divides a product then it divides one of the factors of the  product. So what can you conclude from this lemma when you are given that the prime $\,p\,$ divides the product $\,b^2 = b\cdot b\,?\ \ $

Answer (score 4):

Well if you've been granted the theorem for a prime $p$, $ \; p \ | \ bc \implies p \ | \ b$ or $p \ | \ c$ you're pretty much sorted. A direct application would yield $p \ | \ b^2 \implies p \ | \ b$

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you know that $p \mid ab \Rightarrow p \mid a \; \text{or} \; p \mid b$, then if $p \mid b^2$ you have $p \mid b$ or?  What else, $p \mid b$.  And you're done!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 3):

You know that if $p \mid u v$ with $p$ prime then $p \mid u$ or $p \mid v$. You are given that $p \mid b^2$, that is $p \mid b b$. From the above, $p \mid b$.

Answer (score 1):

p divide b ^ 2 is

$ b ^ 2 = pq,  q \epsilon \mathbb{Z} $

If b is prime, it is clear that

$ p = q = b $

else

$ b = (q_1 ... q_n),  q_1...q_n \epsilon \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow b ^ 2 = (q_1 ... q_n) ^ 2$

it's clear that

$ \exists q_i, 1\leq i\leq n$ that $q_i = p$